# Run JSP from netbeans project in Tomcat Server

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, netbeans

Hi I already develop my application using Netbeans IDE.
Now I want to run my application in Tomcat server for actual use. I already copy my project to tomcat/webapps.

But when I tried to run my application:

```
http://localhost:8081/myAppFolder/
```

it gives me an error message :The requested resource (/Opportunities-Registration/) is not available.

I should change the url to make it work:

```
http://localhost:8081/Opportunities-Registration/web/index.jsp
```

How can I open my application using `http://localhost:8081/myAppFolder/` insteand of `http://localhost:8081/Opportunities-Registration/web/index.jsp` ?

Update:
All my servlet is also become 404 not found

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**SOLVED**

```
Solution:
 1. copy .war file which is contained in dist folder of your netbeans project
 2. Place your .war file to tomcat/webapps
 3. Start your tomcat
 4. You are good to go
```